# Finding XML for website to use in Google Sheets IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to find an update XPath to use in google sheets for `=importxml`

http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/

This was the original one I was using, but it now comes up `#N/A`

```
=importhtml("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/","Table",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

still works:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "TABLE", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

but you can try also:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "TABLE", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @player0  I opened a new sheet and that worked, but I'm finding that this one doesn't work ````=IMPORTXML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "//div[@class='row-group']")````